# Read contents of a URL in Android

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I'm trying to figure out how to get the contents of a URL as a String. For example if my URL is http://www.google.com/ I want to get the HTML for the page as a String. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the Java Docs : [readingURL](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)

```
URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            yahoo.openStream()));

String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(inputLine);

in.close();
```

Instead of writing each line to `System.out` just append it to a string.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before and I just realized my problem: I forgot to give it internet permissions...

Comment: If you post code examples which seem to be doing the right thing, it gives everyone else a chance to figure out what else could be causing the problem (like your permission issue).

Comment: can you get it all in one string at once or do you have to append it line by line?

Comment: since API 11 remeber about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: the code should be inside AsyncTask or any background thread.

Answer (score 6):

You can open a stream and read and append each line to a string - remember to wrap everything with a try-catch block - hope it helps!

```
String fullString = "";
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    fullString += line;
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: How would I write the try-catch block? I'm pretty new and Java is telling me to handle exceptions. Also: fullString is the output, isn't it?

Comment: @SamanMiran try-catch is used in java for doing something that might raise an exception, and catching that exception. try {// do something risky } catch (Exception exception) {// handle it}

Comment: @SamanMiran yes - fullString is the output; you can see that it starts as an empty string ("") and in every loop of the while block - another line is being added to it in the end

Comment: Using String like that is very bad: you allocate a new String object in every step of the loop. Use a StringBuilder instead, and append to it. Use StringBuilder.toString() to get the resulting String.

Answer (score 5):

You can put it in an AsyncTask like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    try {
        new Main2Activity.MyTask().execute(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    Main2Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        activity = (Main2Activity)params[0];
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");

            BufferedReader in;
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            url.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(inputLine);

            in.close();

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
        //Do something with result string
        WebView webView = activity.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        webView.loadData(str, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
    }

}
```