# Activity has leaked windows that was originally added here

Tags: android

Basically I am getting this error and I am not sure what part of the code is causing it, just looking for some advice on what is wrong, thanks.                                                                                                                                                                     .

```
   public class ViewHole extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> holesList;


// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_holes = "http://localhost/realdeal/get_hole_details.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_COURSEONE = "courseone";
private static final String TAG_HOLENUMBER = "holenumber";
private static final String TAG_INDEX = "index";
private static final String TAG_YARDAGE = "yardage";
private static final String TAG_PAR = "par";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray courseone = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewhole);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    holesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new loadallholes().execute();



/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all holes by making HTTP Request
 * */
class loadallholes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewHole.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading holes. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All holes from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_holes, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("All Holes: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // holes found
                // Getting Array of hole numbers
                courseone = json.getJSONArray(TAG_COURSEONE);

                // looping through All holes
                for (int i = 0; i < courseone.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = courseone.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String holenumber = c.getString(TAG_HOLENUMBER);
                    String index = c.getString(TAG_INDEX);
                    String yardage = c.getString(TAG_YARDAGE);
                    String par = c.getString(TAG_PAR);




                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_HOLENUMBER, holenumber);
                    map.put(TAG_INDEX, index);
                    map.put(TAG_YARDAGE, yardage);
                    map.put(TAG_PAR, par);





                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    holesList.add(map);
                }
            } 


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ViewHole.this, holesList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_HOLENUMBER, TAG_INDEX, TAG_YARDAGE, TAG_PAR},                            
                        new int[] { R.id.holenumber, R.id.index, R.id.yardage, R.id.par });

                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

Logcat errors -

```
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566): Activity com.example.golfapp.ViewHole has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40cdf768 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.golfapp.ViewHole has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40cdf768 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at com.example.golfapp.ViewHole$loadallholes.onPreExecute(ViewHole.java:121)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at com.example.golfapp.ViewHole.onCreate(ViewHole.java:61)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-27 04:11:57.228: E/WindowManager(3566):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

JSON class -

```
      public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Comment: why you are using runOnUiThread in onPostExecute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no need to use `runOnUIThread()` over here.

`onPostExecute`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        if(pDialog.isShowing()){
             pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                 ViewHole.this, holesList,
                 R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_HOLENUMBER, TAG_INDEX, TAG_YARDAGE, TAG_PAR},                            
                 new int[] { R.id.holenumber, R.id.index, R.id.yardage, R.id.par });

                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

and cancel the `pDialog` in `onDestroy()` like this,

```
if(pDialog != null ){
     pDialog.cancel(); 
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but when I tried your suggestion I am getting an FATAL EXCEPTION :AsyncTask #1 in doInBackground()

Comment: are you getting data in holesList?

Comment: I am also getting these errors -   01-27 05:21:41.248: E/Buffer Error(4291): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-27 05:21:41.328: E/JSON Parser(4291): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: ohh parsing error, thats why your doInBackground() not working. can you able to put your json.toString() here?

Comment: Ok I put the JSONParser class in the original post at the bottom

Comment: i think no need to JSONParser see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696995/async-android-json-parser-android-null-pointer-exception/15697550#15697550

Comment: Not sure how to implement this into my own version.

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecute() is the UI thread. So runOnUIThread() is erroneous. Also, I would consider separating your AsyncTask from the activity it's in. It will be vastly more reusable in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        url_all_holes);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            String yourReponseInJSONStr = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                    responseHandler);
            //you will get json string here
            Log.d("yourReponseInJSONStr ", yourReponseInJSONStr );

            //check here your getting json string in logcat.
           JSONObject yourJsonObj = new JSONObject(yourReponseInJSONStr);

           JSONArray results = jObject.getJSONArray(TAG_COURSEONE);

           for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
              //your parsing snippet
           }
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Where exactly should I be putting this code and should I be removing anything?

Comment: put this code in doInBackground() from firstline and keep your for loop as it is. but first check the response you are getting from server.Log.d() if you are getting no response server then it will throw you json parsing error.

Comment: The code is giving me many problems, is there any way I can send you the files?

Comment: send on my email amolsawant88@gmail.com

Comment: change one line in forwarded code : JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);