# How to extract XML data to a string via URL

Tags: java, android, xml, string, parsing

I wanna convert xml data from [URL](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.php) to json using this [library](https://github.com/smart-fun/XmlToJson) , but it doesn't handle xml from URLs..! only if it was a string or file, so I wanna convert the data inside the url into a string!

is it possible?

Comment: So you want to have the data that is returned by the url's server as a String? Did you do some research?

Comment: Have you tried to download data to string first and then convert it?

Comment: @f1sh yes that's what i want , I did  a lot, tried different kinds of solutions in here but it didn't work

Comment: @Artyom didn't think of that, any source where I can follow !?

Comment: @SamZar and which solutions did you try? Why don't you post code and describe what exactly is not working?

Comment: @f1sh ok, let me post them..

Comment: @SamZar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075836/read-contents-of-a-url-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fragment can help you

```
 new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            URL url = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("your url");

                in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                url.openStream(),"UTF-8"));//in most cases there is utf 8

                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    builder.append(inputLine);
                String urlContent = builder.toString();
                // process your received data somehow
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```